# Сортировка двумерного массива Java по первой строке

Tags: java, массивы, сортировка

Дан двумерный java-массив, где в первой его строке записаны буквы латинского алфавита в нижнем регистре, при этом они могут повторяться. Нужно отсортировать столбцы в массиве так, чтобы первые элементы каждого столбца были отсортированные в алфавитном порядке от a до z?

Comment: Сами столбцы изменяться не должны, меняется лишь их расположение в массиве

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Реализация функции `sort`:

```
private static void sort(char[][] arrayIn, int start, int end) {
    //массив, который будем сортировать
    char array[] = arrayIn[0];

    if (start >= end) return;

    int i = start, j = end;
    int cur = i - (i - j) / 2; 

    while (i < j) {
        while (((int)array[i] <= (int)array[cur]) && i < cur) {
            i++;
        }
        while (((int)array[j] >= (int)array[cur]) && j > cur) {
            j--;
        }
        if (i < j) {
            //меняем столбцы i и j местами
            swap(arrayIn, i, j);

            //вносим изменения в массив, который сортируем
            array = arrayIn[0];

            if (i == cur) {
                cur = j;
            } else if (j == cur) {
                cur = i;
            }
        }
    }
    sort(arrayIn, start, cur);
    sort(arrayIn, cur + 1, end);
}

private static void swap(char[][] array, int i, int j) {
    // Перемещаем столбцы
    for (int k = 0; k < array.length; k++) {
        char buff = array[k][i];
        array[k][i] = array[k][j];
        array[k][j] = buff;
    }
}
```

Пример вызова для массива `char[][] arr`:

```
    char[][] arr =
            {
                    {'b', 'f', 'g', 'a', 'z', 'o'},
                    {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'},
                    {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'},
                    {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'},
                    {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'}
            };

    sort(arr, 0, arr.length);

    for (char[] anArr : arr) {
        for (char anAnArr : anArr) {
            System.out.print(anAnArr + "  ");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
```

Вывод:

```
a  b  f  g  o  z  
4  1  2  3  6  5  
4  1  2  3  6  5  
4  1  2  3  6  5  
4  1  2  3  6  5
```

Answer (score 1):

Для этого достаточно воспользоваться одним из известных алгоритмов сортировки, например, быстрой сортировкой. При этом реализовывать его нужно вручную, так как придется менять метод swap(), в котором теперь нужно поменять столбцы массива (так как менять столбцы в массиве не очень удобно, можно при получении исходных данных индекс столбца данного элемента поменять с индексом строки. При выводе это тоже следует учесть). Или же создать класс, хранящий двумерный массив, в котором переопределен метод сравнения:

```
class ArrayContainer implements Comparable<ArrayContainer>{
    public char[] data; 
    @Override 
    public int compareTo(ArrayContainer other){
        return ((Character)data[0]).compareTo((Character)other.data[0]);
    }
}
```

Далее создается массив ArrayContainer, сортируемый с помощью одних из имеющихся способов сортировки, например, Arrays.sort()