# Сортировка двумерного массива методом Arrays.sort();

Tags: java, массивы, сортировка

Всем привет.
У меня маленькая проблема, не могу отсортировать двумерный массив.
Я только начал изучать `java`.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне сделать сортировку правильно?

```
int[][] arrayD ={{2,3,1,5,4},{6,8,7,10,9}};

for (int i = 0; i < arrayD.length; i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < arrayD.length; j++) {

     }
}

Arrays.sort(arrayD);

for (int i = 0; i < arrayD.length; i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < arrayD.length; j++) {
     }
}
for (int[] is : arrayD) {
     System.out.println(is + " ");
}
```

Comment: Какого рода сортировку вам необходимо выполнить? Судя по цифрам, предполагаю, что нужно отсортировать массив либо по возрастанию, либо по убыванию?

Comment: Да,  по возрастанию)

Comment: Если Вы ещё не дошли до компораторов, то можно использовать вот такое решение: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/618038/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-java-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5

Answer (score 2):

Используйте это:

```
Arrays.sort(arrayD, new Comparator<int[]>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(int[] o1, int[] o2) {
        return Integer.compare(o2[1], o1[1]);
    }
});
```

В `Java 8` можно поступить проще:

```
Arrays.sort(arrayD, Comparator.comparingInt(arr -> arr[1]));
```

Где `arr[1]` - колонка, по которой будет происходить сортировка.

Comment: `Переопределяем`? Мб, правильнее `используем вторую версию метода sort`?

Comment: @Flippy ошибся, исправил, благодарю.

Comment: `Arrays.sort(arrayD, Comparator.comparingInt(arr -> arr[1]));`
а как так же, только в реверс отправить?)